# How do you redirect output from ifconfig up

Tags: linux

```
$: ifconfig > /dev/null  
$: ifconfig eth0 down  
$: ifconfig eth0 up &> /dev/null  
Nov  3 22:06:13 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: Options: 0x3fa   
Nov  3 22:06:13 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: allocating interrupt 20 for dma mode tx.  
Nov  3 22:06:13 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: allocating interrupt 19 for dma mode rx.  
Nov  3 22:06:15 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: speed set to 100Mb/s  
Nov  3 22:06:15 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: Send Threshold = 24, Receive Threshold = 4  
Nov  3 22:06:15 kernel: eth0: XLlTemac: Send Wait bound = 254, Receive Wait bound = 254
```

Why isn't all output redirected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not output from `ifconfig` (`ifconfig eth0 up` normally doesn't produce any output). They are log messages from the kernel. Your syslog configuration is evidently set to print these messages on your terminal. You can change your syslog configuration by editing `/etc/syslog.conf` (or some other file, depending on your distribution and its or your choice of syslog daemon). You'll probably want to change a line like `kern.info: root` to `kern.alert: root` (there are too many possible variations to list here, check the `syslog.conf` man page to see what there can be, and post the contents of the file if you can't find the line to change).

Answer (score 0):

You only redirected standard out, not standard error.  Try:

```
ifconfig eth0 up >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Same result. :(